# ngIf to find substr

Tags: angular

```
       <ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let head of channelDisplayHeads">
        <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let channel of channelList" ngIf="channel.channel.indexOf('head') === 1">
          <strong>{{ head }}</strong>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Here the ngFor loop displays group heads like "A", "B", "C" etc. For each group head I am trying to list the channels starting with that letter in which the for loop is in. I am trying to accomplish this behavior using ngIf, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. Please advise!

Comment: plz try *ngIf instead of ngIf

Comment: Hello, thanks for the instant response. That was a typo, tried it with *ngIf, it gave a template parse error inside the browser console.

Comment: I think you also want to remove the single quotes around head. I assume you want to use the value of the variable head, not the string `"head"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues here.

1. Your syntax for ngIf is incorrect. It needs to be `*ngIf`.
2. You cannot have both `*ngFor` and `*ngIf` on the same element. Use `ng-container` for one of them. This is angular's element which will not be rendered in the html and is only for angular directives.
3. You seem to be passing the `head` variable as a string. If you want to check for the element, remove the quotes.

   ```
    <ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let head of channelDisplayHeads">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let channel of channelList">
        <li class="list-group-item" *ngIf="channel.channel.indexOf(head) === 1">
           <strong>{{ head }}</strong>
        </li>
      </ng-container>
    </ul>
   ```

Comment: There's also the mistake that head is passed as a string, not the value of the iteration variable.

Answer (score 2):

Finally this code worked as expected

```
 <ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let head of channelDisplayHeads">
                <h1>{{ head }}</h1>
                <ng-container *ngFor="let channel of channelList">
                  <li class="list-group-item" *ngIf="channel.channel.substr(0, 1) === head">
                    <strong></strong>
                    <strong>{{ channel.channel }} </strong>
                  </li>
                </ng-container>
              </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

your forgot `*` here , please include it as given below and try it out,

```
 *ngIf="channel.channel.indexOf('head') === 1"
```

Following is working for me

template

```
   <ul *ngFor="let hero of numbers"  >  
   <div *ngIf="hero==1">
   {{hero}}
   </div>
   </ul>
```

ts file

```
  numbers: Array<string> = new Array<string>();
  constructor()
  {
    this.numbers.push('1');
    this.numbers.push('2');
    this.numbers.push('3');
  }
```

Comment: I added the *, it is giving me a template parse error on the browser console. How do I use "includes()". I am trying to list the channels that start with the alphabet in the "head" which is in the ngFor.

Comment: @sumchans - you have to add *ngIf at below level element because you cannot include both *ngFor and *ngIf at one leavel, i updated my answer with code have look to it

Comment: @sumchans - for you , you have to include ngIf her  <strong *ngIf="channel.channel.indexOf('head') === 1">{{ head }}</strong>

Comment: @sumchans - let me know is that work for you or not, and dont forget to mark answer as accepted if it works for you

Comment: The recommendation of includes is misplaced here. It simply does something different — the requirement is that the string *starts* with head.

Comment: Hello all, thanks for all the responses, so far it is not working as expected. I am not sure If I explained the scenario well here. Here the head array has all the alphabets. I am trying to display the channels grouped by alphabets.

Comment: @sumchans - suggest you to accept answer atlest for the efforts

Answer (score 1):

`ngIf` and `ngFor` on the same element isn't supported. use `ngIf` inside `template`

```
<ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let head of channelDisplayHeads">
    <h1>{{ head }}</h1>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let channel of channelList">
        <li class="list-group-item" *ngIf="channel.channel.substr(0, 1) === head"> <strong></strong> <strong>{{ channel.channel }} </strong> </li>
    </ng-container>
</ul>
```

Comment: Finally this code worked as expected.<ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let head of channelDisplayHeads">
            <h1>{{ head }}</h1>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let channel of channelList">
              <li class="list-group-item" *ngIf="channel.channel.substr(0, 1) === head">
                <strong></strong>
                <strong>{{ channel.channel }} </strong>
              </li>
            </ng-container>
          </ul>

Comment: @sumchans great. i see u used the `ng-container`